# The Script command issue

Tags: command-line

The `script` command typescripts of everything displayed on your terminal.
But sometimes when the output is in colors, it's complaining `"output.txt" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?` if `output.txt` is the output of the session.

Is there a work-around?

Comment: 1) After the facts: You could probably strip out the escape codes that cause the colors to display using `sed` or `awk`. 2) Before the facts: Alternatively, disable any color display in the terminal so that none of these codes is generated and makes it to the script.

Comment: @vanadium - how to disable/enable color display?

Comment: I would have written a full answer if I knew.

Answer (score 1):

[*`ansi2txt`*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/ansi2txt.1.html) can be used to filter out the color escape codes.

Fore more options see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6534556/724406